# Cannot set Traefik via "labels" inside docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

Traefik simply ignores "labels" configuration.

Following [Traefik's main documentation page](https://docs.traefik.io/), we can simply do:

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - ./docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events

  whoami:
      image: emilevauge/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

Then, running docker-compose should be enough (without traefik.toml file):

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Results in the expected:

```
Starting test_traefik_1 ... done
Starting test_whoami_1  ... done
```

But unfortunately, Traefik's dashboard displays nothing:

> No providers found

What have I tried to do:

- To use also another [labels](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels) notation:

> ```
> labels:
>   traefik.backend: "whoami"
>   traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
> ```

- To follow [this guide](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/traefik/deploy-load-balancer).
- To remove "version: '3'", and also changing it to "version: '3.3'".
- To run `$env:DOCKER_HOST="npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"` or `$env:DOCKER_HOST="tcp://localhost:2375"` on Powershell.
- To set npipe instead of unix socket:

> ```
> volumes:
>   - type: npipe
>     source: ./pipe
>     target: /pipe/docker_engine
> ```

Nothing works.

Right now, the only way I can see something in the dashboard, is by adding this line to Traefik volumes: "- ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml", while creating "traefik.toml" file with [file] configurations. I don't want to have this file. I want to have the control inside the "lables" inside docker-compose.yml.

It'll also be nice to know when should I use the traefik.toml file, as opposed to setting lables inside docker-compose.yml. I did not see any information on that.

**Edit:** docker logs of traefik shows UNIX socket is in use:

> time="2018-07-23T10:55:38Z" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve
>   information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to
>   the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon
>   running?"
>
> time="2018-07-23T10:55:38Z" level=error msg="Provider
>   connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?, retrying
>   in 13.276739006s"

Docker-compose [should use npipe protocol on Windows by default](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/release-notes/docker-compose/#190-2016-11-16), but it doesn't. Trying to set the Windows' pipe explicitly, to take place instead of the UNIX socket ([using npipe of the long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#long-syntax)):

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3.2'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: npipe                # here we are
        source: ./pipe
        target: /pipe/docker_engine
```

But still the logs shows:

> time="2018-07-23T10:57:18Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error
>   Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?, retrying in 4.166259863s"
>
> time="2018-07-23T10:57:23Z" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve
>   information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to
>   the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon
>   running?"

Comment: Can you post the docker logs of traefik ?

Comment: @OlivierCazade Yes, I've added the logs. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is related to how the docker.sock is mounted. Just a guess but if you run whoami using docker run (without docker-compse), you will have the same error. I don't know how docker on windows work, so, I can not help more.

Comment: I would expect docker to use named pipes (npipe) instead of docker.sock (unix sockets) on Windows 10 (as docs says). Seems like a bug. Thanks @OlivierCazade

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to use:

```
volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Only with this workaround in Powershell:

```
$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

The reason is this opened bug: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1829
which makes it impossible to mount docker.sock, because it is "not a valid Windows path" (error).

Answer (score 0):

The docker.sock file is located at /var/run/docker.sock on a linux environment, not the current directory. Therefore the volume mount is incorrect in your example for a linux environment. That compose file would look like:

```
version: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  whoami:
      image: emilevauge/whoami 
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

Since you are running the command on windows, the docker api is accessed [via an npipe or tcp connection](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api). The solution to this appears to be (this may depend on your version of docker for windows):

```
version: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker --docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - //./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine

  whoami:
      image: emilevauge/whoami 
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I used your solution (withouth volumes, right?), and got this error log: `Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.21/version: dial tcp: lookup //./pipe/docker_engine: no such host`. It seems `//./pipe/docker_engine` path is missing somehow. But at least I'm not getting any unix sockets errors anymore. What would you suggest me to try?

Comment: If I'm using your volumes, I'm getting an error when creating the container: `ERROR: for test_traefik_1  Cannot create container for service traefik: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\\\\\.\\\\pipe\\\\docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine"\nis not a valid Windows path'`

Comment: @TechWisdom The solution listed above had a volume listed. If it doesn't exist for you, then it may have been moved or be a version dependent path. Did you ever try the full path, /var/run/docker.sock, as both the source and target of the socket. That relative path you had won't work on windows or linux.

Comment: I've just tried full paths: `- //./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine` and got: `ERROR: for traefik  Cannot create container for service traefik: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\\\\\.\\\\pipe\\\\docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine"\nis not a valid Windows path'`. Also `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` shows: `ERROR: for traefik  Cannot create container for service traefik: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run\\\\docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"\nis not a valid Windows path'`. My host is Windows 10, and I do use full paths as you described. What's wrong?